# Issue with user defined function in R

Tags: r, function

I am trying to change the data type of my variables in data frame to 'factor' if they are 'character'. I have tried to replicate the problem using sample data as below

```
a <- c("AB","BC","AB","BC","AB","BC")
b <- c(12,23,34,45,54,65)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
str(df)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "AB" "BC" "AB" "BC" ...
 $ b: num  12 23 34 45 54 65
```

I wrote the below function to achieve that

```
abc <- function(x) {
  for(i in names(x)){
    if(is.character(x[[i]])) {
      x[[i]] <- as.factor(x[[i]])
    }
  }
}
```

The function is executing properly if i pass the dataframe (df), but still it doesn't change the 'character' to 'factor'.

`abc(df)`

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr  "AB" "BC" "AB" "BC" ...
 $ b: num  12 23 34 45 54 65
```

NOTE: It works perfectly with for loop and if condition. When I tried to generalize it by writing a function around it, there's a problem.

Please help. What am I missing ?

Comment: Let your function return `x` and then do `df <- abc(df)`.

Comment: As @Roland said. Functions in R don't act by reference. If you change a function argument inside the function, the object stays unchanged outside the function. Plus, you need your function to `return(x)` at the end.

Comment: @Roland and Nicola thanks for your suggestions. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the comment from @Roland, you should make use of R's nice indexing possibilities and learn about the `*apply` family. With that you can rewrite your code to

```
change_to_factor <- function(df_in) {
    chr_ind <- vapply(df_in, is.character, logical(1))
    df_in[, chr_ind] <- lapply(df_in[, chr_ind, drop = FALSE], as.factor)
    df_in
}
```

**Explanation**

- `vapply` loops over all elements of a list, applies a function to each element and returns a value of the given type (here a boolean `logical(1)`). Since in `R` data frames are in fact `lists` where each (list) element is required to be of the same length, you can conveniently loop over all the columns of the data frame and apply the function `is.character` to each column. `vapply` then returns a boolean (logical) vector with `TRUE/FALSE` values depending on whether the column was a character column or not.
- You can then use this boolean vector to subset your data frame to look only at columns which are character columns.
- `lapply` is yet another memeber of the `*apply` family and loops through list elements and returns a list. We loop now over the character columns, apply `as.factor` to them and return a list of them which we conveniently store in the original positions in the data frame

---

By the way, if you look at `str(df)` you will see that column `b` is already a factor. This is because `data.frame` automatically converts character columns to characters. To avoid that you need to pass `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `data.frame`:

```
a <- c("AB", "BC", "AB", "BC", "AB", "BC")
b <- c(12, 23, 34, 45, 54, 65)
df <- data.frame(a, b)

str(df) # column b is factor
# 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "AB","BC": 1 2 1 2 1 2
# $ b: num  12 23 34 45 54 65

str(df2 <- data.frame(a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: chr  "AB" "BC" "AB" "BC" ...
#  $ b: num  12 23 34 45 54 65

str(change_to_factor(df2))
# 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "AB","BC": 1 2 1 2 1 2
#  $ b: num  12 23 34 45 54 65
```

---

It may also be worth to learn the `tidyverse` syntax with which you can simply do

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% 
  str()
```